# What is a better word for thought?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word for thought but better conveys the meaning I want. An example sentence in the context I would like is, "The lemonade was sweeter than I thought". I came to the word *expected*, but I think there are more suitable words. What are synonyms that I could use that would be better for the word thought?

Comment: "thought" is a formal word in English. Not sure anything is more "sophisticated".

Comment: Could you please explain why you need a a more sophisticated word for thought?  Can you suggested a couple of statements to illustrate how the the use of the word 'thought' is too unsophisticated?

Comment: I should have clarified that I meant sophisticated as in better. I do not think thought is an unsophisticated word but I feel that there is a better word choice I could have made in the context. I'll edit my post to reflect that.

Comment: What is the "meaning [you] want"?

Comment: I wanted to use thought or a similar word in reflection. I was writing about the outcome of an experience I had. It was surprising and not what I had expected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A bit of this will depend on context.

*Contemplate* can be used, with the shades of meaning.

> to view as likely or probable or as an end or intention

This matches the *expected* suggestion.

> to view or consider with continued attention : meditate on

This shows there was a deeper consideration, which may or may not match the case. If someone absent-mindedly threw back a glass, the first definition matches but not the second. If there was a serious consideration, both work well.

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contemplate)

Comment: Thank you for the quick and thorough answer! I need this word for a midterm I am taking at the moment(I was given permission to ask this question by my teacher).

Comment: *anticipated* would fit.

Comment: You really contemplate the sweetness of lemonade?

Comment: @UnrealApex — You realize that you were cheating. I only hope that your teacher thinks this answer is as bad as I do.

Comment: Let me clarify that I was explicitly given permission to ask this question on the Internet by my teacher. The midterm was an open self reflection essay. There is not really a way to cheat on it, they stated this. They also specifically stated my class could collaborate on it.

Comment: I apologize for the miscommunication, I realize that my comment did give the suggestion of that. Intent is hard to decipher online but I know you are acting in good faith.